# Error on Convert.ToDateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this code:

```
public JsonResult salvaPaciente(string cns, string sexo, string dataNasc, string nome, string raca,
                                string cep, string ibge, string logradouro, string endereco, string numero,
                                string complemento, string bairro, string telefone, string email)
{
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-8").GetBytes(nome);
    nome = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

    paciente oPaciente = new paciente()
    {
        bairro = bairro,
        cep = cep,
        cns = cns,
        complemento = complemento,
        dataNasc = Convert.ToDateTime(dataNasc),
        email = email == "" ? " " : email,
        endereco = endereco,
        ibge = ibge,
        logradouro = logradouro,
        nacionalidade = "010",
        nomePaciente = nome,
        numero = numero,
        raca = raca,
        sexo = sexo,
        telefone = telefone
    };
    modelOff.pacientes.Add(oPaciente);
    try
    {
        modelOff.SaveChanges();
        return Json("sim", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json("nao", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The code was working and crash after I actuallize the Visual Studio 2017 and generate the error below:

> [FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]

The string `dataNasc` contain '24/06/1979'

Comment: Is that *always* the format of the date value? If so, I'd strongly recommend that you parse it very explicitly with that format, with the invariant culture.

Comment: Use `DateTime.Parse()` instead

Comment: `dataNasc = DateTime.ParseExact(dataNasc, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`: when you have predefined format let parser know it

Comment: Have you tried DateTime.ParseExact ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

sample:-

```
string dataNasc = "24/06/1979";
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(dataNasc, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

[Online Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GVguoQ)

Answer (score 1):

24/06/1979 will not convert so you will need to parse it first.

[DateTime Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/parsing-datetime)